# Validate 3 digit number or not

Tags: javascript, regex

can anyone tell me the regular expression to check whether the entered number is 3 digit number or not... it should not allow alphabets also....

Comment: Added `regex` tag for relevance.

Comment: tip: play with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regex for 3 numbers would be `^[0-9]{3}$` or `^\d{3}$`

Answer (score 8):

```
^\d{3}$
```

and more chars to pass my answer

Comment: You'll need to anchor it, otherwise it'd match "123test", "test123" or "test123test".

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm, it wouldn't if you validate using [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function: `/^\d{3}$/.test('123test')`.

Comment: @manakor: The `^` and `$` are the anchors. The original was just `\d{3}`. `/\d{3}/.test('123test') === true`. So yes, you need the anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Here you go.    ^[0-9]{3}$  OR ^\d{3}$

The "^" and "$" at the beginning and the end of each specify that the string being compared must be exactly 3 digits.  if you omit those, then dsaasd888adsad would be a match because \d{3} is being matched SOMEWHERE in the string.

Or you could google "regex 3 digit number".

Personally, I always go here for regex examples: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3

Answer (score 1):

`\d\d\d` or `\d{3}` should work for a 3 digit number.  This won't allow any punctuation, letters, symbols, etc - it's specifically 3 numerals.  If you need to allow for a decimal point, that's going to be a little different.